# How to prepend a path by UriComponentsBuilder?

Tags: java, spring, uri

I would like to prepend a path by Spring's `UriComponentsBuilder`. However, it looks like that its [`path()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html#path-java.lang.String-) method can only append paths.

For example, I would like this code to work:

```java
UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("/foo?name=john");

// prepend "/bar" in the path in some way

String uri = uriComponentsBuilder.build().toUriString(); // so that "uri" can be "/bar/foo?name=john"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What about using buildAndExpand to replace path token with your prepend path:

```
   String uri = UriComponentsBuilder
                .fromUriString("{prePath}/foo?name=john")
                .buildAndExpand("bar")
                .toString();

    System.out.println(uri);
```

Which should give you:

```
bar/foo?name=john
```